# Testing Many-Worlds Interpretation (MWI) with a causality-violating configuration of “superluminal cables”

Tags: quantum-interpretations, causality, thought-experiment

Suppose we managed to [arrange a causality-violating transmission of data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147491/) with [hypothetical “superluminal cables” (SLC](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147076/); see both links for respective descriptions) and expect, similarly to [ideas popularized by David Deutsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#Paradoxes), that it might result in communication from one “alternative reality” to another. Exact schemes may vary from the simple “send a word from a future and receive (the same or another) word in a past”.

Main questions are:

- How should we analyse the data received to investigate possible differences between quantum interpretations?
- How could experimenters **reliably** verify “several alternative realities” condition, debunking possible alternative explanations?

Any analysis of the setting leading to non-obvious implications, even speculative, can be considered a satisfactory answer. Ī only ask to describe carefully conditions of an experiment, see the two bottommost questions  below.

Supplementary questions (Ī desire to consider them to some extent, but not require it for a satisfactory answer) are:

- How could this condition (even short-lived) be exploited?
- Would transmission of quantum information over an SLC offer some gains over transmission of purely classical information?
- Should a difference between physical principles behind our SLCs (such as General Relativity vs a hypothetical anomalous Lorentz symmetry-violating solid) influence quantum aspects of the experiment??

Comment: Related by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147076/

Comment: First of all there is no superluminal communication, each device proposed during the years was shown to encapsulate a mistake. Your question is similar to "what would happen if the 2nd principle of thermodynamics didn't exist? But it exists. Next, between WHICH quantum interpretations you want to distinguish? Name them. There are some well investigated interpretations, and there are many ad-hoc.

Comment: @Sofia: Ī do not assert a superluminal communication actually **exists,** but it can be conjectured.

Which interpretations? Different flavours of MWI (including branching space-time, [my preferred](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5585)) on one hand, and Copenhagen and “realism” (a.k.a. hidden variables) on opposite hand. Ī’m not a good expert on quantum interpretations, but Ī hope that a causality-disrupting experiment can provide arguments in favour or against some other known interpretations too, notably von Neumann–Wigner.

Comment: Please see, I am not an expert in gravity - this would be your domain in this talk. I can only refer to the quantum theory, and some of the interpretations, those that I consider very well elaborated, not ad-hoc. There are many from the latter type. So, you ask what it would be IFF we could beat the light velocity? Then, YES, we could choose between Bohm's interpretation of the quantum theory (interpretation that I actually investigate) and the Copenhagen interpretation. But, there is NO superluminal communication. And that is to our luck.

Comment: (continuation) If the superluminal communication existed, the world wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Sofia: inertial frame of reference (IF **R**), you meant? The “world wouldn't exist” arguments is null: read the thread on SLC proper to understand better which form of “superluminal communication” do Ī assume. In short, not in vacuum or ordinary media, but in specially constructed devices (that are not very likely possible naturally) and only along pre-arranged paths.

Comment: @Sofia BTW, Bohm's interpretation is not on very good terms with relativity, so it must be modified in some way only to face hypothetical “signal loop” condition as such.

Comment: @Incnis: ***all*** interpretations of quantum mechanics must be modified in some way to deal with hypothetical "signal loop" conditions. How do you know that there are not five different ways of modifying the many-worlds interpretation to deal with closed time-like loops, and that some of these are equivalent to ways of modifying the Copenhagen interpretation to deal with closed time-like loops?

Comment: @Peter Shor: you are right that there is, potentially, an unbounded number of versions of QM interpretation, as well as extensions. The question of today is which extended quantum world theories **may produce verifiable implications for given type of** (imaginary) **experiment.** Possibly, these implications/predictions will be extrapolated to less “acute” situations that *can* be checked experimentally. Then, let Occam's razor do necessary refining job for such theories in the future.

Comment: @Peter also Ī’d avoid relativistic (i.e. “closed *time-like*”) language describing (possible, or perceived) looping of **causal** time. Ī do not require the signal world line to be (time or light)-like in the sense of Lorentzian metric, a thing Ī denote as the “mechanical time”. Construction of SLCs *can be* Lorentzian metric-based, but has not necessarily so. But the thing that **is** important is considering cables instead of topologically non-trivial (namely, non-simply connected) things such as wormholes: Ī am not interested in inquiries of a MWI based on covering 4-manifolds.